# Azure Powershell function Scale SQL DB

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I am pretty new to Azure & very new to azure powershell functions.  I am trying to create a script that will scale my DB to S7 as a test.  I have watched a view videos read some docs and seen some examples and everything indicates this shouldn't be 2 difficult.  I have been trying for a couple of days and I am stuck.  I run the code below and the only response I get is,

status 500 internal server error. in the output area on the portal.  Have hit a bit of a wall and not sure what to do next to figure out.

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
$name = $Request.Body.Name
}


#my script
$Database = Set-AzureSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "rgcmacproduction" -ServerName "sql" -      DatabaseName "DW" -Edition "Standard" -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S7"     
#end of my script


if ($name) {
    $status = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    $body = $Database
}
else {
$status = [HttpStatusCode]::BadRequest
$body =  $Database 
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
StatusCode = $status
Body = $body
})
```

Comment: Do you see the ""PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request." message in your script? Start simple - run a script that _only_ has that Write-Host line and get it working

Comment: ANd you are running the script directly from the Azure Automation portal? YOu aren't trying to use a webhook? Don't plug in a chuck of code and expect it to work. Start small (i.e. `Write-Host`), get that working, then add more code.

Comment: Try this and see if it helps : https://hacksbyme.net/2017/11/22/schedule-scaling-of-your-azure-resources/

Comment: Hi I used the template that ran the Write-Host part that all worked great,  I believed it was just a one line entry to get it to scale.  I am running direct in the portal not trying use a webhook.

Comment: So you see the Write-Host part then you see the 500 error?

Comment: Nothing is written to the log stream at the moment.

Comment: I think this issue is connected to MSI which is something new to me